# How does the RequestAttributes.InternalNetworkAccess works?

Tags: servicestack

How does the **RequestAttributes.InternalNetworkAccess** works? Does it filter by IP ranges? Or how does it know whether it is an internal network or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant implementation is in [IPAddressExtensions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/IPAddressExtensions.cs) where it just checks to see if the Request IPv4 or IPv6 is [in the same subnet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/d3bd362038be660518d8fa9d87cff2ba17139502/src/ServiceStack/HttpRequestExtensions.cs#L801) as the local network interfaces returned by .NET's `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`.